# argument list command not correct

Tags: powershell

I used the below that works for wusa.exe but it is not working for pkgMGr.exe - I get an error of "The pkgmgr.exe command is incorrect"

I think it is because of the

WORKS:

```
Start-Process c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe -ArgumentList "$ItalianHyphenationHotfix /quiet /norestart /log" -Wait
```

NOT WORKING:

```
Start-Process c:\windows\system32\pkgmgr.exe -ArgumentList "/ip /m: $ItalianKB2841134Hotfix /quiet /norestart /l:C:\buildlog\complogs\LangPack" -Wait
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? I tried to put the /ip /m before the -Argument list but that did not work as well. I think it is because of these two commands that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ArgumentList` should be a string array, so you need to format your parameters as such. Try:

```
Start-Process c:\windows\system32\pkgmgr.exe -ArgumentList "/ip", "/m:`"$ItalianKB2841134Hotfix`"", "/quiet", "/norestart", "/l:`"C:\buildlog\complogs\LangPack`"" -Wait
```

Comment: Thanks for that - but still not working - same error. I tried to move the parenthesis around but no such luck yet. Was wondering if I can do write-host to see what the command looks like?

Comment: actually - my mistake - seems like it is working - thanks for that!